# how to integrate backgrid with backbone layoutmanager

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backgrid

This is my code :

```
beforeRender : function() {
    var columns=[{name:'hq_name',label:'Headquarter Name',cell:'string'},{name:'description',label:'Description',cell:'string'}];
    var grid=new Backgrid.Grid({
        columns:columns,
        collection:this.collection
    });
    this.insertView(grid.render().el);
}
```

it's throwing this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '**manager**' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

I run in the same issues integrating BackGrid with Backbone Boilerplate + (Lodash + backbone.layoutmanager).

The above suggestion from the author doesn't work for me.

You have to be sure that the manage property in Backbone.LayoutManager.configure is set to false. Otherwise the inner render methods (body,header, etc..) of BakGrid won't work as expected.

```
Backbone.LayoutManager.configure({
    manage: false
});
```

Lodash v 1.2 with underscore compatibility v. seems to work fine in first trials.

Btw: thank you Y.H Wong for your good work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
this.insertView(grid.render().el);
```

Try this:

```
this.insertView(grid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 
   this.insertView(grid.render().el);
Try this:
    this.$el.append(grid.render().el);